# Hausman's specification test for "glmer" from lme4

Tags: r, random, panel

I want to make a "Fixed/Random Models for Generalized linear model" (family="binomial"), because I have a data base where observations come from a population and there is a grouping structure. Then I use the function `glmer` from the `lme4` package, also I have read that I can use the `glmmPQL` function from library `MASS` (Faraway,2006).

My problem arises when I want to justify the use of random versus fixed model using the Hausman's test (Greene,2012), I don't find a specific function that allows me to do this similar to the `phtest` test featured in the package `plm`.

How to justify using the random model?

Comment: can you give a little more information? I found the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausman_test) but I'm not sure what b_0 and b_1 represent: are they just the fixed-effect covariates (i.e. not including the grouping variable)?

Comment: thaks for your help! 
I'm worried because I don't find a specific function within R, especially in the lme4 package to perform this test, so I doubt if it could be done. Or if instead I can justify otherwise the random model best fits the data (anova).

There a question similar: 
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/fixed-vs-random-effects

Comment: I'm not sure with the explanation of wikipedia, so I show you the Greene definition.
"The test is bases that under the hypotesis of no correlation, both OLS, LSDV and FGLS estimators are consistent, but OLS is inefficient, whereas under the alternative, LSDV is consistent, but FGLS is not. Therefore, under the null hypothesis, the two estimates should not differ systematically, and a tes cam be based on the difference"(Greene, 2012).

Comment: Example fron Greene: "we retrieved the coefficient vector and estimated asymptotic covariance matrix, b_fe and V_fe from the fixed effects results and the first nine elements of B_re an V_re (excluding the constant term)" [I don't know why nine first elements.]
H=(b_fe - B_re)' [V_fe - V_re]^-1 (b_fe - B_re)

Comment: the anova won't work particularly well because it is tricky to justify the requirement that one model is nested within the other (as is necessary for the likelihood ratio test to apply).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a straightforward tweaking of the `plm::phtest` function. I've commented on the only lines of code that I actually changed. **USE AT YOUR OWN RISK** and if at all possible test it against the results from `plm::phtest`. I have just adapted the code, not thought about whether it's really doing the right thing!

```
phtest_glmer <- function (glmerMod, glmMod, ...)  {  ## changed function call
    coef.wi <- coef(glmMod)
    coef.re <- fixef(glmerMod)  ## changed coef() to fixef() for glmer
    vcov.wi <- vcov(glmMod)
    vcov.re <- vcov(glmerMod)
    names.wi <- names(coef.wi)
    names.re <- names(coef.re)
    coef.h <- names.re[names.re %in% names.wi]
    dbeta <- coef.wi[coef.h] - coef.re[coef.h]
    df <- length(dbeta)
    dvcov <- vcov.re[coef.h, coef.h] - vcov.wi[coef.h, coef.h]
    stat <- abs(t(dbeta) %*% as.matrix(solve(dvcov)) %*% dbeta)  ## added as.matrix()
    pval <- pchisq(stat, df = df, lower.tail = FALSE)
    names(stat) <- "chisq"
    parameter <- df
    names(parameter) <- "df"
    alternative <- "one model is inconsistent"
    res <- list(statistic = stat, p.value = pval, parameter = parameter, 
        method = "Hausman Test",  alternative = alternative,
                data.name=deparse(getCall(glmerMod)$data))  ## changed
    class(res) <- "htest"
    return(res)
}
```

Example:

```
library(lme4)
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
                   data = cbpp, family = binomial)
gm0 <- glm(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period +  herd,
                   data = cbpp, family = binomial)

phtest_glmer(gm1,gm0)
##  Hausman Test
## data:  cbpp
## chisq = 10.2747, df = 4, p-value = 0.03605
## alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

This seems to work for `lme` models too:

```
library("nlme")
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont) # random is ~ age
fm0 <- lm(distance ~ age*Subject, data = Orthodont)
phtest_glmer(fm1,fm0)

## Hausman Test 
## data:  Orthodont
## chisq = 0, df = 2, p-value = 1
## alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```